# What are SRIDs like 30008 in an SDE geodatabase?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

When I look at the `SDE.ST_GEOMETRY_COLUMNS` table of my SDE database I'm seeing mostly recognizable four-digit values, but a number of columns have SRIDs like `300006`, `300008`, and `300047`. I can't find descriptions of these anywhere and they aren't recognized when I use an open-source library like Proj4 to transform geometries. Does anyone know what these signify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Esri SRID is not the same thing as a coordinate reference ID.  Esri uses an integer compression algorithm to improve geometry performance, and the spatial reference parameters provide the rules for this compression (there's a whole [whitepaper on how coordinate references are implemented](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/whitepapers/view/productid/17/metaid/1301)).  The SRIDs are therefore site-specific versions of the metadata associated with as-built geometry layers, and are not to be used as a coordinate system id.

Coordinate system identifiers for the ArcSDE Oracle implementation are stored as both text and well-known ids in the `sde.ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCES` table, in the `DEFINITION` and `CS_ID` columns, respectively.  In PostgreSQL, the spatial references are stored in `public.sde_spatial_references`, in the columns `srtext` and `cs_id`, respectively.  The `SRID` from `sde.layers` and `sde.st_geometry_columns` is the foreign key into the spatial references table.

Comment: Thanks Vince, that makes a lot more sense. I'm still a little puzzled that those would be returned by the `SDE.ST_SRID` function rather than the more canonical coordinate system ID. I don't always have permissions to select from `sde`, so I'm not sure how to reliably translate the Esri SRID to an EPSG-style ID.

Comment: SDE.ST_SRID predated the canonical use of CR ids.  The spatial references table has PUBLIC access, so you should be able to join to it on srid to return CS_ID.